# characteristic function in definition of a probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, characteristic-functions

I came across this function in a paper (used to compute the distribution of some real-valued random variable $\lambda_{c}$):

$$\large f({\lambda})=\sum\limits_{c \in C_{S}} \frac{\chi_{\{\lambda\}}(\lambda_{c})}{\#(C_{S})}$$

$\lambda$ is a logit value calculated from two probability values (i.e., $\lambda=ln\frac{p}{1-p}$, where p is some probability value); for each $c$, there's one and only one logit value. ***The distribution of $\lambda$ is unknown and not assumed before hand; it may vary depending on the configuration of original model***.

$\chi$ is the characteristic function (quote the paper, it was actually characterization function) for $\lambda$;

$C_{S}$ represents all the possible combinations if we choose $k=S/2$ items from $S$ items;

$c$ accordingly refers to a single combination in $C_{S}$, where $c \in C_{S}$;

$\#(C_{S})$ effectively denotes the total number of combinations.

I don't understand the use of characteristic function here. Given the distribution of $\lambda$ is unknown before hand (and can be estimated from observations), to capture the $pdf$ of some $r.v.$ like $\lambda$, do mathematicians use characteristic function for contingency? Or is there a particular reason for the use of characteristic function in this case?

[here](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/backtest-prob.pdf)'s a link to the paper and the formulae is towards the end of page 12. The contextual information was on page 10-11.

If there's more information needed please let me know.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ ? In the definition of $f$, is $\lambda_c$ a random variable ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon $\lambda$ itself is a logit function, in that case it is ($-\infty$, $\infty$); and yes $\lambda_{c}$ is a random variable in $f's$ definition.

Comment: The term "characteristic function" here is being used in the combinatorialist's sense: $\chi_A(x)$ is 0 or 1 depending on whether $x\notin A$ or $x\in A$, not the probabalist's sense of $E\exp(itX)$.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks for the input, that makes sense now.

Comment: Same thing as the indicator function, which is the more common terminology in probability (the symbol $\chi_S$, and the name "characteristic function," for this object are more common in measure theory).